# How to make the navigation by clicking an image?

Tags: objective-c, ios

In my application, i created imageView dynamically for each image and i have placed them in a scrollview.
How to generate an event to perform navigation action by clicking each image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Quick and easy to implement**

And an `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the `UIImageView` using `addGestureRecognizer`.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageViewTapped:)];
singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
singleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
[theImageView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
[theImageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

Now the following is triggered when the view is tapped:

```
- (void)imageViewTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    NSLog(@"%@", [gestureRecognizer view]);
}
```

**Alternative solution**

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if ([[touches anyObject] view] == theImageView)
    {
        // ImageView tapped.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use `UIGestureRecognizer`**. In your case, simply add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` on each of your `UIImageView`. **Don't forget to turn on `userInteractionEnabled`** on your `UIImageView` so that the taps are considered.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer* tapGR = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageViewAction:)];
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:tapGR];
imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

-(void)imageViewAction:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)tapGR
{
    UIImageView* imageView = tapGR.view;
    // Do something with your imageView
}
```

**Read [the Event Handling Guide for iOS (Apple Doc)](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH6-SW1)** for details about how Gesture Recognizer works and how to use them, and examples and stuff. This Apple Guide is really worth reading and contains very helpful notions and explanations.